# match text of a div with any input textbox in html using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a filter for the users page, I will show all the user on page and will provide multiple filter .
There will be one filter -filter by skilled and the field will be token field .
user can insert multiple skills separated by comma .
but the problem begins from here -
I am not able to match the field, could you please suggest me script for doing the same .
here is my page :

http://sigrideducation.com/gurgon/rem.html
(Look into skills field)

Example for company I am doing this

```js
$(".nameCompany").keyup(function () {
  jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function (a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase().trim()) >= 0;
  };

  var userString = $('.nameCompany').val();
  $('.company1:not(:contains(' + userString + '))').parents().closest('.galcolumn').css('display', 'none');
  $('.company1:contains(' + userString + ')').parents().closest('.galcolumn').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="panel panel-default user-box">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="media">
        <img src="images/people/50/guy-4.jpg" alt="people" class="media-object img-circle pull-left" />
        <div class="media-body">
          <a href="#" class="username name1 All">Anurag</a>
            <div class="profile-icons">
              <span><i class="fa fa-users"></i> 372</span> <span><i class="fa fa-photo"></i> 43</span> <span><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> 3 </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body bordered">
        <p class="common-friends">Details</p>
        <div class="user-friend-list">
          <table class="UTb">
            <!--<tr>
               <td>Name</td><td class="name1 All">ashwani</td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
              <td>Company</td><td class="company1 All">HDFC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Skills</td><td class="skills1 All">Dealing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Location</td><td class="location1 All">Gurgaon</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Industry</td><td class="industry1 All">Agriculture</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>College</td><td class="college1 All">IIM</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <a href="profile.html" target="_blank" class="btn  btn-sm">View Profile <i class="fa fa-share"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put relevant code with multiple users in table into codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3gxLvk/ here is the fiddle
i am looking for a solution if i write anything in textbox and press comma then its hide all the table dont have that text and show all the table have text (wrote in textbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. You need to create an array from the string and then loop through it.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/oeq2dm5u/1/

```
$(".skills-input").keyup(function () {

        jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function (a, i, m) {
            return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase().trim()) >= 0;
        };

        var skillsArray = $('.skills-input').val().split(",");

        $.each(skillsArray, function( index, value ) {
            $('.skills1:not(:contains(' + value + '))').parents().closest('.galcolumn').css('display', 'none');
            $('.skills1:contains(' + value + ')').parents().closest('.galcolumn').css('display', 'block');
        });      
    });
```

**Edited based on jsfiddle provided**

The field is pipe delimited behind the scenes when using token. You can then add a call back via the token creation function.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/sv3gxLvk/1/

```
$('#tokenfield')
  .on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
    var skillsArray = e.attrs.value.split('|');
    $.each(skillsArray, function (index, value) {
        $('.skills:not(:contains(' + value + '))').parents().closest('table').css('display', 'none');
        $('.skills:contains(' + value + ')').parents().closest('table').css('display', 'block');
    });
  })
.tokenfield()
```

Comment: Dude you are genius. I will use this logic to fix a similar issue i am having with form parsing.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/sv3gxLvk/
please have a look on that 
i am looking for a solution if i write anything in textbox and press comma then its hide all the table dont have that text and show all the table have text (wrote in textbox) –

Comment: really you are genius i got stuck on this problem from last night .....thanks a lot you save my time .hats off